# Create multiple mailboxes on Centos-6-i386-ISPmanager

Tags: centos

I have a VPS with Centos-6-i386-ISPmanager installed on it.
I can create mailboxes manually but I want to add multiple "E-mail domains" and want to create multiple mailboxes over them.
Can someone help me with this?
A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any pannel like cpanel or plesk on your vps, you can easily add domain and email accounts with it. but if not you need to setup domain on your server add entry in httpd.conf, register mx record for your domain and add users.